# Is it safe to store ONLY the credit card number for receiving payments purposes?

Tags: credit-card

Hi I am developing an application where the vendors save their bank account number and credit card number ONLY so that their clients can go to the bank and pay them. This information is given because a large base of the buyers do not hold a credit card for electronic payment purposes.

The question is, can they display such information naked over the Internet? They do not show expiration date nor the back numbers in the card.

Any help will be very appreciated.

Just to give you an example users in mercadolibre.com store that information in ML's auto-generated emails. I am concerned there might be a way to commit any fraud with ONLY such information.

Answer (score 1):

Yep, it's a formal and engraved invitation to fraud.  Transactions can definitely go thru without an exp date or the CVV code (try donating thus on Obama's web site) all it would take would be the credit card number - do not implement anything like this or even close to it!

Comment: Thanks Ron. Well, Obama's does ask for the expiry date.